# Eclipse outline view does not display a sort icon

Tags: eclipse, outline-view

I would like to sort my javascript outline view. But since I have installed Eclipse 2019-06 version (EDITED : javascript & web dev version), I have no more A-Z icon to sort the methods. Any clue on what is wrong? (I have the Maximize, Minimize, View and Focus icons only)

Comment: Which 2019-06 download/feature?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was able to fix it by :

- downloading LiClipse on Eclipse marketplace
- closing and reopenning all js files

JS files appeared in the project view with an icon with a handle bar sign and now they appear with a JS icon. And the sort icon is back.